# gitlab-runner clone code failed, The requested URL returned error: 500

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Alibaba Cloud took a gitlab server, did not resolve the domain name, and bound the hosts 127.0.0.1 git.server.
Another machine had gitlab-runner to build the code, and the host on the machine also bound 116.*.*.194  git.server, there is no problem with using ssh to clone code normally.

When building with runner, the following error occurs: fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.server/tuitui/test-ci.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500

```
/etc/hosts
116.*.*.194 git.server

[[runners]]
  name = "api-tuitui"
  url = "http://git.server/"
  token = "2dbcbaba3*********e3499064"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]

Grant root user ：gitlab-runner install --user=root --working-directory=/var/www
```

Running with gitlab-runner 11.4.2 (cf91d5e1)
  on admin 83a7c629
Using Shell executor...
Running on iZwz98jvb8bcz3jj1i5x2mZ...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/83a7c629/0/tuitui/test-ci'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.server/tuitui/test-ci.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
bash: line 61: cd: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/83a7c629/0/tuitui/test-ci: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Comment: I already add ssh key on gitlab server